# Using CURL download file in FTPS server but output have the wrong size

Tags: curl, ftp-server

I'm trying to download a file in FTPs server by CURL but when I use 2 commands it will give 2 different results.
Example: I have the file fileName.zip have size is 40mb.

When I use the first command:

**curl --insecure -u username:password ftps://host:port//download/folder1/fileName.zip --output fileNameDownload.zip**

It will return for me the file fileNameDownload.zip with size 40MB, this file is OK.

And I try another way to download this file with the command:

**curl --insecure -u username:password ftps://host:port -X "RETR download/folder1/fileName.zip" --output fileNameDownload.zip**

It will return for me the file fileNameDownload.zip with size 40.2MB and I cannot open this file.

How to make the second command correct?

Comment: Do you have looked into the second file with a text editor? I assume that it contains header information at it's start.

Comment: I'm already trying to test it again with textFIle.txt file and the second command working OK, but when I zip the textFile.txt to textFIle.zip and download again with the second command it will return the testFile.zip but I cannot unzip this file

Comment: And when I open 2 zip file with a text editor and copy the content to https://www.diffchecker.com/diff and it said "The two files are identical"
but the 1st command gave me a file with size 701byte and 2nd command gave me a file with size 704byte

Comment: ![Different from two file](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2018/10/5/8a9e20080f7a518437d6730f5f340989-full.png).
I found the different from two file

Comment: Are you using the latest curl version? On which platform? If not please try them - if so I think it's worth opening a bug report: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/bugs.html

Comment: I found the problem because I used -X option and CURL have a script for this in the script have stepped to set TYPE = A.

(In the 1st command CURL set TYPE = I;)

A TYPE request controls the binary flag. It has a parameter. There are four possibilities for the parameter:

A: Turn the binary flag off.
A N: Turn the binary flag off.
I: Turn the binary flag on.
L 8: Turn the binary flag on.

That is the reason why I download file with wrong content.

Comment: Cool, so you could write your own answer here now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem because I used -X option and CURL have a script for this. In the script have stepped to set TYPE = A. (In the 1st command CURL set TYPE = I)

A TYPE request controls the binary flag. It has a parameter. There are four possibilities for the parameter:

A: Turn the binary flag off.

A N: Turn the binary flag off.

I: Turn the binary flag on.

L 8: Turn the binary flag on.

That is the reason why I download file with wrong content